# Hide element if not element in a list iteration

Tags: typo3, typoscript

So I have 2 list of string in 2 fields, *altText* and *imagecaption*. I have them wrapped in a div. I want to make the div not render if neither have content in some loop, on each iteration of the loop. How can I do it?

```
            30 = COA
            30{

                wrap = <div class="case-info">|</div>
                required = 1

                30 = TEXT
                30{
                    wrap = <div>|</div>
                    field = altText
                    listNum.splitChar = 10
                    listNum.stdWrap.data = register:SPLIT_COUNT
                    required = 1

                }

                40 < .30
                40.field = imagecaption


            }
```

The output of html is this:

```
<div class="case-info">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add, which TYPO3 Version do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the wrap and try it this way:

```
        30 = COA
        30{
            stdWrap.required = 1
            stdWrap.wrap = <div class="case-info">|</div>
            30 = TEXT
            30{
                field = altText
                listNum.splitChar = 10
                listNum.stdWrap.data = register:SPLIT_COUNT
                trim = 1
                required = 1
                wrap = <div>|</div>
            }

            40 < .30
            40.field = imagecaption


        }
```

so, the wrap will only executed, if there is content (required = 1)

Comment: It didnt work :( This is the backend: http://awesomescreenshot.com/09b2fn4eb and this is how the frontend looks: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0462fnb27 How you see the second box hasnt disappeared yet

Comment: would be helpfull, if you tell us, which HTML-part get rendered. The 30 is the COA not the TEXT object.

Comment: I added the whole typoscript. Check your HTML Source if <div class="case-info"> exists and is empty.

Comment: This gets rendered: <div class="case-info"><div></div><div></div>/div>

Comment: well, the inner <div></div> should not happen. Perhaps there are whitespaces left? I added trim = 1. There should not be an empty <div></div>. Perhaps \r is left? Should be removed by trim. If the inner <div></div> are removed, the outer should disapear.

Comment: Can you add 30.30.ifEmpty = empty and 30.30.ifBlank = blank does it change the output?

Comment: Yeah! That did it! :) The bounty is yours :) Edit the code and I accept the answer :)

Comment: sorry, i do not understand, what the solution is. ifBlank / ifEmpty should not change, but only show if there really is no output.

Comment: Weird. I have taken them out and it still works... Maybe I didnt clear the cache after including the "trim". :P